# Deploying ktor Server on Debian

Tags: java, api, kotlin, ktor

I have recently wrote an API with ktor but i want to deploy and it on debian linux server.Does someone have any idea, how to deploy ktor server on debian?

Comment: I think a few more details will be helpful, are you trying to build a jar file to run, are you wondering how you can set up CI/CD, do you have a jar file and are just wondering how to run it on your server? As far as I can tell, none of your tags really apply that well to your question aside from maybe the ktor and api tags.

Comment: Here https://ktor.io/docs/deploy.html you can find some information about deployment

Comment: @undermark5 Thank you for the answer. I'm just wondering if it is possible to deploy a web application with kotlinjs/react (which is deployed with nginx) and use ktor as backend on debian 10.

Comment: It is indeed possible, but that doesn't seem to be what your question is asking, your question seems to be asking how to do it, and there are a lot of ways to do it. Simplest is to build a jar that you can execute via `java -jar` and copy that to the server, then run it on the server via ssh and the above command. Is this the most bullet proof way of deploying? Definitely not, but it is a way.

Comment: @undermark5 thanks a lot. Is there any other way that you would recommend?